# Choosing null hypothesis with t-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, multiple-regression, t-test

I'm studying for my final and came across this practice question. I realized that it's always been the case that $H_0 = 0$ in my homeworks and exams, but I don't think it's necessary.

It also seems like the answer to this question must be A because the t-statistic of $b_1$ is

$b_1 = \frac{-1.0306}{.4612} = -2.84$

Since the absolute value is greater than $1.692$ (the provided critical value), I understand this makes the independent variable statistically significant.

Am I understanding this correctly?

[image]

Comment: Include self study tag.

Comment: Added self-study tag

Comment: Check your division and be careful about the significance level in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find:

$$t=\frac{1.0308}{0.4612}=2.2350$$

so, at 1% significant level (which require t>2.445), I fail to reject $H_0$.

So I would choose answer C.

Comment: Why would the hypothesis be correct for C and not B?

Comment: Because the language of the question and the critical value are one-tailed.